# How to correctly use the linear-gradient?

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am pretty new in CSS3 and I have the following style in a CSS file of my project:

```
.headerDiv {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04519b, #044687 60%, #033769);
    ............................
    ............................
    ............................
}
```

It is pretty clear to me what 
`linear-gradient(#04519b, #044687 60%, #033769);` 
should do (it creates a vertical gradient as a background of a div with the class name `headerDiv`.

I have to change it the colors of the gradient, so I found on Google this documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

The problem is that I can't find the syntax used in my CSS file.

So related to my:

```
linear-gradient(#04519b, #044687 60%, #033769);
```

what exactly represent the:

1) First value (**#04519b**)

2) Second value (**#044687 60%**), what does 60% mean?

3) Third value (**#033769**)

I know that these are changing the gradient color but I don't know the exact ordered and what 60% means.

Comment: This should help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gradient `linear-gradient(#04519b, #044687 60%, #033769);` can be interpreted as follows:

- The gradient is from top `to bottom` of the `div`. This is the [default direction](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) which is used if no angle (like `45deg`) or no direction (like `to right`) is specified.
- The first color (that is at `0%`) is `#04519b`. If no [color-stop position](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) is specified for the first color then it is assumed to be 0% as per spec.
- The `60%` is a [color-stop position](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax). That is at `60%` of the height of the gradient image, the color should exactly be `#044687`.
- This implies that between 0% and 60%, the color gradually changes from `#04519b` to `#044687`.
- The final color (that is at `100%`) is `#033769`. Similar to the first color, if no position is specified for the last color, it is assumed to be at 100%.
- This implies that between 60% and 100%, the color gradually changes from `#044687` to `#033769`.

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(#04519b, #044687 60%, #033769);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: The explanation is fine, but is there ANY point in coding a linear gradient by hand? Also, the gradient will not work properly in some browsers. I think coding a gradient manually should be discouraged as a waste of productive time and a source of errors.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: I don't see any need for it to be discouraged. I code all my linear gradients by hand because it gives more understanding of what is being done. It could be personal choice but I prefer it this way. Browser support or differences? Well, that's something that we can never truly overcome but from my experiences, gradients are reasonably stable in all supported browsers.

Comment: For one thing, you are unlikely to include all the edge cases for all the somewhat obscure browsers that people do use because it's a pain in the neck. And even if it's only a few percent of the visitors, on a reasonably big website, that's thousand of people. For another, it is slower, except for very simple gradients, and it is a pain to try on dozens of different gradients. Graphic design is a visual process for the most part. I am all for coding by hand if the resulting code will be better, but if not, what's the point?

Comment: @Sylverdrag: I guess the question is more about an explanation and the discussion on whether to hand code it or use a tool is off-topic. Let us just say each of us have their own preference and leave it at that.

Comment: @Sylverdrag Even if you use a generator, **understanding** the specification won't hurt anybody

Answer (score 0):

This is syntax for `linear-gradient`

```
background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);
```

**direction**

```
left,right,toright,..
left top,bottom right,..
180deg,80deg,90deg..
```